# Replication in SQL Server 2008 R2 if Source and Destination Tables are different Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

1. Source and Destination Tables are different Name
2. Source and Destination Filed names are different
3. Source and Destination field type different ... not all the time...need to check source field type is bit and destination field type is tinnyInt
4. Check how insert, update and delete will work
5. How do we setup the replication when databases are on different servers and replication on different server

Ex:  DB1 on Server 1, DB2 on server 2 and Replication on Server3

Need to check how do we setup the credentials etc  ......

Answer (score 0):

The replication being on a different server is somewhat standard (given enough budget for enough servers), one distributor serving one publisher and multiple subscribers, etc.

Merge or Transactional?